Message not received by worker service when files have been updated in JavaScript
I'm trying to force the update of some of my web app JavaScript files without having the client having to press Ctrl+F5 to force the refresh of these files but I'm having dreadful problems with the last part where I want to update my local storage with the remote version of my cache if the files were successfully updated.
Here's my worker service code:
const urlsToCache = [
   ... My JavaScript files are defined here.
];

let CACHE_NAME = '';

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    self.skipWaiting();
    console.log('Service Worker: Install event triggered.');
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    console.log('Service Worker: Activate event triggered.');

    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
                    if (cacheName !== CACHE_NAME) {
                        console.log('Service Worker: Deleting old cache:', cacheName);
                        return caches.delete(cacheName);
                    }
                })
            );
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('Service Worker: Old caches deleted.');
            // Claim clients only after old caches are deleted
            return self.clients.claim();
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('Service Worker: Clients claimed, sending updateComplete message.');
            self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
                clients.forEach(client => {
                    client.postMessage({ type: 'updateComplete' });
                    console.log('Service Worker: Sent updateComplete message to client:', client);
                });
            });
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    if (event.data && event.data.type === 'CACHE_NAME') {
        CACHE_NAME = event.data.value;
        console.log('Service Worker: Received CACHE_NAME:', CACHE_NAME);

        event.waitUntil(
            caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
                console.log('Service Worker: Opened cache:', CACHE_NAME);
                return Promise.all(
                    urlsToCache.map((url) => {
                        return cache.add(url).catch((error) => {
                            console.error('Service Worker: Failed to cache:', url, error);
                            return Promise.reject({ url, error });
                        });
                    })
                );
            }).then(() => {
                console.log('Service Worker: All resources have been cached successfully.');
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error('Service Worker: Failed to cache some resources:', error);
            })
        );
    }
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then((response) => {
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});

and here's the code I'm calling from my web app:
function registerServiceWorker(remoteVersion) {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/Scripts/service-worker.js')
            .then(registration => {
                console.log('Client: Service Worker registered:', registration);

                if (registration.active) {
                    console.log('Client: Active service worker found, sending CACHE_NAME message.');
                    registration.active.postMessage({ type: 'CACHE_NAME', value: remoteVersion });
                } else {
                    registration.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {
                        const newWorker = registration.installing;
                        if (newWorker) {
                            newWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                                if (newWorker.state === 'activated') {
                                    console.log('Client: New worker activated, sending CACHE_NAME message.');
                                    newWorker.postMessage({ type: 'CACHE_NAME', value: remoteVersion });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }

                navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
                    console.log('Client: Message received from Service Worker:', event.data);
                    if (event.data.type === 'updateComplete') {
                        console.log('Client: Update completed, updating version in LocalStorage.');
                        localStorage.setItem('version', remoteVersion);
                        console.log('Client: Version in LocalStorage updated to:', remoteVersion);
                    }
                });

                registration.update();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Client: Service Worker registration failed:', error);
            });
    }
}

Everything seems to work correctly (i.e. registration, previous cache is deleted, new files are fetched and cached) except for the message 'updateComplete' being received:
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    console.log('Client: Message received from Service Worker:', event.data);
    if (event.data.type === 'updateComplete') {
        console.log('Client: Update completed, updating version in LocalStorage.');
        localStorage.setItem('version', remoteVersion);
        console.log('Client: Version in LocalStorage updated to:', remoteVersion);

I stop & unregister the specific service worker from my browser, delete my cache (not that I have to since it seems to always be doing it!) and press ctrl+f5 to force the refresh of code to ensure that the worker and the page that contains the 'registerServiceWorker' function are definitely refreshed but to no avail.
I've spent hours on this and just can't spot what I'm doing wrong. Anyone can spot anything or suggest a better way to do this?
Thanks.

Have you tried stepping line by line through the code with your debugger? From your description I understand that you can see the output Client: Message received from Service Worker:, but not Client: Update completed, updating version in LocalStorage.. Can you check the value of event.data.type with your debugger? Maybe a typo?
